# Construct GraphQL Query in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I want to construct below query and pass params dynamically in Java.

```
query {
 testAPI(query:"java") {
    page 
    pageCount 
    documents {
      id
      ... on Document {
        title
        updated
        subjects{
            id
            name
            url
        }
        rating {
            average
            count
        }
        categories {
            id
            name
            url
            subcategories {
                id
                name
                url
            }
        }
        images {
            px100x100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using below dependencies in my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-webclient-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

below is the code snippet, the way I am doing it right now,

```
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://test.com/graphql")
                .build();
        GraphQLWebClient graphqlClient = GraphQLWebClient.newInstance(webClient, objectMapper);

        GraphQLRequest request = GraphQLRequest.builder()
                .query("query {\n" +
                        " testAPI(query:\"java\") {\n" +
                        "    page \n" +
                        "    pageCount \n" +
                        "    documents {\n" +
                        "      id\n" +
                        "      ... on Document {\n" +
                        "        title\n" +
                        "        updated\n" +
                        "        subjects{\n" +
                        "            id\n" +
                        "            name\n" +
                        "            url\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "        rating {\n" +
                        "            average\n" +
                        "            count\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "        categories {\n" +
                        "            id\n" +
                        "            name\n" +
                        "            url\n" +
                        "            subcategories {\n" +
                        "                id\n" +
                        "                name\n" +
                        "                url\n" +
                        "            }\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "        images {\n" +
                        "            px100x100\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "      }\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "}\n")
                .build();
        GraphQLResponse block = graphqlClient.post(request)
                .block();
```

Currently the search criteria in the query is a hard coded value(java). I need to achieve following things

1. Make the search criteria dynamic. (Primary objective)
2. Make the query construction dynamic i.e adding the required fields dynamically. (Secondary Objective)

Answer (score 0):

I not sure where your confusion lies - the graphql query is just a string from the point of view of Java - you just need to build the string dynamically.

So in response to your first question (how to pass a parameter):

```
String MyValue="java";
GraphQLRequest request = GraphQLRequest.builder()
                .query("query {\n" +
                       " testAPI(query:\""+MyValue+"\") {\n" +
...
```

In a similar manner the fields returned by the query can be controlled by building this string dynamically like:

```
String fields;
if (briefVersion) fields="  page \n pageCount \n"
else fields="  page \n pageCount \n ...{all the rest of the fields}"
GraphQLRequest request = GraphQLRequest.builder()
                .query("query {\n" +
                       " testAPI(query:\""+MyValue+"\") {\n" +
                       fields +
                       "}";
```

So basically the graphQL query is just a string and you can treat it like a string; build it with a string builder (or String.join) and generally play with it as you wish before submitting it to graphql.

This is a bit different to the way it works in typescript/js where the graphql queries are preprocessed.